# Deleting user's account in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have problem with deleting user's account. This is error I received:

```
undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000535a700>:0x00000005358f68>
```

I'm using Devise + omniauth, so my routing looks a little bit complicated for beginner like me.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
  match '/users/:id/finish_signup' => 'users#finish_signup', via: [:get, :patch], :as => :finish_signup
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
  match 'users' => 'users#index', via: :get
  root to: 'static_pages#about'

  get 'static_pages/help'

  resources :categories do
    resources :games, shallow: true
  end

  resources :games, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :comments
  end

end
```

"rake routes" output:

```
                  Prefix Verb      URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET       /users/sign_in(.:format)                     devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST      /users/sign_in(.:format)                     devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE    /users/sign_out(.:format)                    devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST  /users/auth/:provider(.:format)              omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/twitter/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST  /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)       omniauth_callbacks#:action
           user_password POST      /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET       /users/password/new(.:format)                devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET       /users/password/edit(.:format)               devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH     /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update
                         PUT       /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET       /users/cancel(.:format)                      devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST      /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET       /users/sign_up(.:format)                     devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET       /users/edit(.:format)                        devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH     /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#update
                         PUT       /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE    /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#destroy
           finish_signup GET|PATCH /users/:id/finish_signup(.:format)           users#finish_signup
                         GET       /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                   users GET       /users(.:format)                             users#index
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :finish_signup]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/:id.:format
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users/:id/edit
  def edit
    # authorize! :update, @user
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/:id.:format
  def update
    # authorize! :update, @user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        sign_in(@user == current_user ? @user : current_user, :bypass => true)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET/PATCH /users/:id/finish_signup
  def finish_signup
    # authorize! :update, @user
    if request.patch? && params[:user] #&& params[:user][:email]
      if @user.update(user_params)
        # @user.skip_reconfirmation!
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.'
      else
        @show_errors = true
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/:id.:format
  def destroy
    # authorize! :delete, @user
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      accessible = [ :name, :email ] # extend with your own params
      accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
      params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
    end
end
```

I don't know why "users_path" did not work as usual, so I added this line to routes.rb:

I'v tried resolve my problem with deleting user's account with this line in routes.rb but this did not worked.

```
match 'users/id:' => 'users#destroy', via: :delete
```

This is my button for removing user's account:

```
= link_to 'Delete user', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm"
```

User is without "@" sign, because it's in iteration loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove these two lines

```
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
  match 'users' => 'users#index', via: :get
```

and replace them with...

```
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]
```

And that will give you the three routes you need for users.

Answer (score 1):

To add to `@SteveTurczyn`'s answer, you can clean your routes up a lot:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
resources  :users, only: [:index, :show, :delete] do
   match :finish_signup, via: [:get, :patch], on: :member #-> url.com/users/:id/finish_signup
end

resources :static_pages, only: [] do
   get :about, on: :collection #-> url.com/static_pages/about
end

resources :categories do
   resources :games, shallow: true
end

resources :games, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
   resources :comments
end

root to: 'static_pages#about'
```

--

Your `link_to` etc looks fine